# Вывод превью товаров по атрибуту в сайдбар Wordpress Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет!

Вопрос: Как можно реализовать такую штуку:

Нужно на странице описания продукта, вывести превьюшки товаров (только картинки) с одинаковым атрибутом.

В качестве примера: Магазин картин, выбрал картину, справа в сайдбаре (под номером 1 отображаются все картины этого автора. Под номером 2 — все картины в таком же стиле как выбранная.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Под номером 1 выведены картины с одним и тем же автором
- Под номером 2 выведены картины с одинаковым стилем
- Номер 3 — как вывести имя автора.

Может есть плагин какой? Или подскажите в какую сторону копать.

Answer (score 0):

> Нужно на странице описания продукта, вывести превьюшки товаров (только картинки) с одинаковым атрибутом.

Отличный плагин, позволяет задавать какую только вздумается логику: [flexible posts widget](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/flexible-posts-widget/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Шаблоны для вывода можно делать свои - инструкция в реадми.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, попробовал этот плагин, почти то что нужно,  но есть один минус, нужно чтобы это работало на странице товара. То есть, в зависимости от того какой товар выбран, изменяется и контент в этом блоке. Например: если выбрана картина художника "Иванов" то должны выводиться все картины с атрибутом "Иванов", а если выбран "Петров", то все картины с атрибутом Петров. А используя этот плагин на любой странице товара(будь то "Иванов" или какой то другой) выводит одинаковые картины заданные в параметрах. Короче нужно чтобы Параметр "того что выводить" менялся динамически) как то так

Comment: Этого не было в ТЗ. Для этого надо что-то типа "похожих записей" применять.